# Looking for email to web service api (e.g. push email inbox to webapp)

Tags: web-services, api, email

There are many email marketing/delivery service providers that offer an api to create and send emails: http://postmarkapp.com, mailchimp, etc.

Does any one know of a web app that offers the reverse: a service that will parse new emails into more api accessible information?

In other words, I am looking for a service that allows me to access an email inbox via an api, preferably having parsed the email content into something like JSON.

Answer (score 7):

Take a look at http://cloudmailin.com/

Comment: I looked at this and am not impressed. I signed up and deselected the "Do you want to subscribe to our emails?" check box, clicked the next step, and got an email indicating I subscribed. Clicking back in the browser confirmed I definitely did not choose this. What part of not subscribing do they not get?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out http://context.io

Answer (score 3):

PostmarkApp now has this functionality:

http://postmarkapp.com/inbound

Answer (score 1):

Might check out http://www.emailyak.com/ and lamsomeproject.